# How can I return a specific DataRow Object from an object context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, wcf-ria-services

I'm working with Entity Framework and Silverlight (RIA) and am looking at creating a function to expand on the CRUD to allow for the user to specify a specific column name, and then a matching value to pinpoint an exact record... The code would look something like this...

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategory(string theColumn, string theCriteria)
{
      return this.ObjectContext.Categories
                .Where(c => c.theColumn = theCriteria);
}
```

The similar working function to get ALL categories... (Created by building after associating a data model)

```
    public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Categories;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built something similar to what you are looking to construct. I built around using Expression trees from System.Linq.Expressions. So I would suggest that you build your where predicate using an expression tree where the predicate has the signature of   `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`.

Some pseudo code below where T is a WCF RIA entity:

```
public static class QueryHelper
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToPredicate<T> ( string propertyName, dynamic criteria )
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ), "t" );
        Expression np = Expression.Property( pe, propertyName );
        ConstantExpression value = Expression.Constant( criteria );

        Expression e1 = Expression.Equal( np, value );

        var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( e1, pe );

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Which could then be used like:

```
var selector = QueryHelper.ToPredicate<Category>("theColumn", "hello");
return this.ObjectContext.Categories.Where(selector);     

LoadOperation<Employee> loader = context.Load( context.GetEmployeesQuery()
                                        .Where( selector ) );
loader.Completed += (op) =>
  {
    if ( !op.HasErrors)
    {
    }
  };
```

Or

```
var selector = QueryHelper.ToPredicate<Category>("theColumn", true);
return this.ObjectContext.Categories.Where(selector);
```

One thing to note is the line Expression e1 = Expression.**Equal**( np, value ); in the function. You could extend this function to do >, <, =>, etc but you would need to check that the property type you were using supported the operator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Slightly confused. It looks like there should be three parameters, but I'm not sure what my entityInstance looks like. Thoughts?

Comment: I missed the 'this' out of the method parameters, it should be an extension method. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Awesome, so what does the call look like?

Comment: Just modified the code sample so that you can use it as indicated in the above entry. Previously it wouldn't have worked. Have another go hope it works this time.

Comment: I think we're close.  But stepping through the function there is a problem with the instantiation of methodql.. Naturally there is no "IsEqualTo" Method inside of Bar.. What is that line supposed to accomplish? I can probably come up with it if I know. :)

Comment: Hi, I've correct the code above again, the MethodInfo should now reflect the = operator. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Now the instantiation of "expression"...  {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.

Comment: Another update - approached the problem from a different direction this function should work.

Comment: Very close now.... return this.context.Employees.Where(selector);  giving 3 errors.... I'm putting them into another answer so you can see them....

Comment: You sir... are a gentleman and a scholar. I appreciate all your time helping me figure this out.... I did this as a side project for a new RIAServices project we're building... I view this type of function as a "one-and-all" solution to returning a specific set of records in the CRUD instead of exposing each column in the domain service. Our database expert believes that with appropriate database design, no one will be searching by anything other than Primary Key, what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Final tag so you can see my previous comment. :)

Comment: Most database tables I've got have GUIDs as primary keys. Your domain might allow using only primary key searches but I would expect to see a lot of different queries required. This might be worth a separate question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this solve your problem or only moves it but you could delegate the predicate to the client of the method like this

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategory(Func<Category, IQueryable<Category>> predicate)
{
      return this.ObjectContext.Categories.Where(predicate);
}
```

then you could call this method by this way

```
GetCategory(c => c.column=criteria)
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<SilverlightApplication2.Web.Category>.Where(string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: how are you make the call to the method?

Answer (score 0):

I initialize my context like this...

```
    NorthwindDomainContext context = new NorthwindDomainContext();
```

I call your method like this...

```
var selector = QueryHelper.ToPredicate<Employee>("theColumn", "hello");
        return this.context.Employees.Where(selector);
```

Also, as I noted, I'm actually using Employee instead of Category.  Thoughts?

Error   1   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.Func'  C:\Code\NorthwindRIA\NorthwindRIA\Views\Employee.xaml.cs    22  49  NorthwindRIA

Error   2   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntitySet' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments C:\Code\NorthwindRIA\NorthwindRIA\Views\Employee.xaml.cs    22  20  NorthwindRIA

Error   3   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntitySet' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'  C:\Code\NorthwindRIA\NorthwindRIA\Views\Employee.xaml.cs    22  20  NorthwindRIA

Comment: I've been testing the QueryHelper on the clientside and it should work for any RIA entity. You would use your context and build a selector as you have but then use a load operation e.g. LoadOperation<Employee> loader = context.Load( context.GetEmployeesQuery().Where( selector));. Then on the completed event work with the returned data.